# Dispatch_async stops UITableView reloading

Tags: ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have a case where I'm reading the contents of UITableview with custom cell's subview inside a dispatch_async() as below:

```
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^ {
    [self filterArrays];
    [self updateSlotData];

} );
```

Inside the updateSlotData: I'm trying to access the uitableviewcell's subview as below:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= [slotTable numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
    SlotDataCell *cell = (SlotDataCell *)[slotTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i-1 inSection:0]];
    NSLog(@"iterating inside %i %i %i",[cell.intTF.text length],[cell.toTF.text length],[cell.fromTF.text length]);

    if(![cell.intTF.text length] || ![cell.toTF.text length] || ![cell.fromTF.text length]){

        outdatedTF = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slot %i timing",i];
        newSlot = false;
        return NO;

    }

}
```

On calling the reload data: 
   isDBSelected = false;
    addMode =false;
    [slotTable reloadData];

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{



if(tableView == slotTable){
    if(isDBSelected){

        if(addMode){

            return [countArray count] + 1;
        }else{


            return  [countArray count];
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"new template creation started");
        return 1;
    }
}
  return  0;
}
```

The table reloads with the first row being initialised to nil. The other rows doesn't seem to disappear. Expected result: Only one row is created.

Comment: Any UI updates must be on main thread.

Comment: @Kreiri If UI updation happen in background thread means , what will happen?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS for that thread

Comment: Im not updating anything on the background thread here. The returned boolean just check the condition and prompts an uialertview on the MAINTHREAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments state, you are accessing `updateSlotData` inside a block on a thread, and that routine uses `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, which belongs to a UI element, and is not on the main thread when used. Also, you cannot directly access a cell that isn't visible, as the table does not keep them around, but recycle just a few cells.

The standard way to do this is to create a mutable array that has the same number of objects as your table. In fact, you can create the array with NSMutableStrings in it, and on your background thread you can update the strings values.

When the table asks for a cell in the delegate method, you recycle or create one, then access the string from the table and update the cell's string. Likewise, if the values change and the table is not scrolling, then you can see if any given row is visible, and if so update the string in that cell.

Note that since your mainthread is reading that mutable array (and string objects), and your background thread is updating them, you need to use some kind of lock to prevent getting corrupt data - a dispatch semaphone is handy for this purpose. Or, you can just update the strings by dispatching to the mainThread, and not worry about concurrent access.